# What causes empty() and append() not to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

The following code snippet should remove any elements in `SubCategoryList`  div first. After that it should start with `<ul class="list-group">` and end with `</ul>`.

```
$list.empty();
$list.append('<ul class="list-group">');
// others
$list.append('</ul>');
```

However, it does not work as expected. It does not clean and it does not sandwich the `<li>` children.

```
<select id="ddlCategories" size="4"
        asp-for="SubCategory.CategoryId"
        asp-items="Model.Categories.ToSelectListItem()"
        class="form-control">
    <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<p>Existing Subcategories:</p>
<div id="SubCategoryList">
    <ul class="list-group" ></ul>
</div>
```

and

```
function updateSubCategoryList() {
    var categorySelected = document.getElementById("ddlCategories").value;
    $list = $('#SubCategoryList');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/SubCategory/GetSubCategory/' + categorySelected,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            results = JSON.parse(data);
            //$list.html('');
            $list.empty();
            $list.append('<ul class="list-group">');
            for (i in results) {
                $list.append('<li class="list-group-item">' + results[i].text + '</li>');
            }
            $list.append('</ul>');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your code is because you cannot append opening and closing tags separately; an element must be created in its entirety.

There's a couple of ways to fix this. Firstly you could create the `ul` in a jQuery object, then `append()` `li` to it:

```
success: function (data) {
  results = JSON.parse(data);
  $list.empty();

  var $ul = $('<ul class="list-group">').appendTo($list);
  for (i in results) {
    $ul.append('<li class="list-group-item">' + results[i].text + '</li>');
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could create an entire HTML string from the `results` array using `map()` and set it to the `html()` of the `$list` in one operation.

```
success: function (data) {
  results = JSON.parse(data);
  var li = results.map(function(obj) {
    return '<li class="list-group-item">' + obj.text + '</li>';
  })
  $list.html('<ul class="list-group">' + li + '</ul>');
}
```

Also note that if you change `dataType: 'text'` to `dataType: 'json'` you can get rid of the `JSON.parse()` call.

Comment: In the first version, there is no closing `</ul>`?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer None is required; this is how jQuery works.

Comment: That's right. jQuery inserts it for you when you create the element. You can add it yourself if preferred. `$('<ul />')`, `$('<ul></ul>')` and `$('<ul>')` will all do the same job; create a `ul` element inside a jQuery object.

Comment: @DaveNewton : thank you. It is very counter intuitive. :-)